# Undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass after installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After installing some gems and deleting them from my gem file, I got this error

```
undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #16):  

    <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:medium)), post %>
```

I have everything in my app exactly the same as before adding the gems, etc. But still I receive this error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Either the image or url methods probably use gsub on an object that is nil. I'd check the bodies of both of these methods.

It may be something with the current data rather than the gem you removed.

Also, if you removed the gem from your Gemfile, did you run bundle install again?

Comment: Yeah I did, but I'm not sure if is the data because everything is there, I even check by console and all posts are there.

Comment: So if you find that post in the console, then run post.image.url(:medium) - you're not seeing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and replace it with:

```
<% if post.image && !post.image.url.nil? %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:medium)), post %>
<% else %>
  <p> Image unavailable! </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Rails convenience method `#try`

```
<% if post.try(:image).try(:url) %>
  <%= link_to (image_tag post.image.url(:medium)), post %>
<% end %>
```

From: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dd7d5b7c800b4f6d32747913fc7c8d00ce94f03a/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L44

> ```
> # +try+ calls can be chained:
> #
> #   @person.try(:spouse).try(:name)
> #
> # instead of
> #
> #   @person.spouse.name if @person && @person.spouse
> ```

---

*Note: `#try` will prevent an error in the view, but not fix underlying issues such as ActiveRecord associations: `post.whatever.whatever`*